# IdentityServer3 integration with Ping Identity. Is it possible?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

We are currently using IdentityServer3 for authentication and authorization with our asp.net MVC(angular.js) and webapi clients.  We are about to bring on a new customer that uses PingIdentity for their Single Sign On(SSO).  The customer would like to be able to integrate their SSO into our application.

Is this possible with IdentityServer3?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to leverage the WS-Federation capabilities that both products have to integrate them. IdentityServer3 playing the Service Provider (or: RP) role, the customer playing the Identity Provider (or: IP) role.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [KentorIT Authservices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices)?  It's a SAML plugin for IdentityServer3.  I was able to add OneLogin SAML authentication with this plugin.

-Scott